# iOS App keeps running forever in the background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, background-process, multitasking

I'm trying to better understand the behavior of Apps in the background in iOS. I have a button with the following action:

> ```
> - (IBAction)createTask:(id)sender {
>
>
>     for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
>         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://agronigeria.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/cocoa.jpg"];
>         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
>         NSLog(@"Image number %d with size %lu", i, (unsigned long)[data length]);
>         NSLog(@"Time before task is killed: %f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
>     }
> ```
>
> }

As soon as I tap the button, I press the home button, sending the App to the background. I was expecting this to stop shortly (what's the maximum time an app, without special background modes, can run in the background, BTW?). Instead, it just goes forever. After 10 minutes I stopped it. It goes on even when `backgroundTimeRemaining` returns 0.

What's going on???

PS I'm running this on a 4S with iOS 7 installed.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios hope this will helps you

Comment: On iOS 7 there is an entry in the general part of the settings menu. It's called 'refresh apps in the background', it has to do with keeping apps alive in the background when possible. Is that feature turned on?

Comment: @Kevin It was indeed turned on. I turned it off, and I'm getting the same behaviour. :-(

Comment: I added your code to a new project and I get the same behaviour. Sometimes backgrounding gets messed by being connected to xcode, so to test this I added a label to the view and replaced the contents of your function to replace the text of my label. I pressed the button and then the home button, waited for over a minute and went back to the app. The text was still changed, so something got changed regarding backgrounding of apps on iOS 7. If I test the same thing on iOS 6.x the text is changed back if I return to the app after more then 5-10 seconds.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact the app is doing mostly io...

Answer (score 0):

check if you have the following function

**application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler**

Seems simple but try to add this line or remove the handler function

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalNever];
```

Comment: will this solution keep app live in background?

Comment: not necessarily - from apple :
setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:
Specifies the minimum amount of time that must elapse between background fetch operations.

minimumBackgroundFetchInterval
The minimum number of seconds that must elapse before another background fetch can be initiated.
This value is advisory only and does not indicate the exact amount of time expected between fetch
operations.
Discussion
This property has no effect for apps that do not have the UIBackgroundModes key with the fetch value in
its Info.plist file.